# Continue program after Exception is caught, without using loops?

Tags: java, class, exception

I've got a program which declares an array of Apartment objects. Each Apartments has an address, a number, a bedroom count, and a rent price. When the array is initialised, each apartment is given a string, and the Apartment class' constructor turns that string into values. The program is a test study in Exception throwing and catching using multiple classes.

Everything is currently working as it should, the Apartments are created, the string is properly converted to object parameters, and the exception is properly thrown and caught, however, currently, when the exception is caught, the program ends. I am unsure what to do about this issue. I believe that I could restructure the program so that the exception is caught inside the Apartment constructor itself, but if that doesn't work it'd be a major waste of time so I've decided to search, and then ask, on here first.

Here is the code for the "main" class in the program, with the current output below it:

```
public class ThrowApartmentException
{
public static void main(String[] args)
{
  // this program uses three classes, the ThrowApartmentException class is the "main" class, it's what you run to use the program. The Apartment class is used to create 
  // apartment objects, and it converts apartment Strings into values, checks those values for validity, and throws an exception if those values are wrong. This exception 
  // is an ApartmentException, which is the third class. It takes the apartment string as an argument and simply prints a message stating that the apartment failed to be 
  // instantiated.

  // this class creates an array of 6 apartment objects, with both valid and invalid values, and an appropriate message is displayed when one is instantiated successfully 
  // and one is not.

  Apartment[] apartments = new Apartment[6];
  // apartment string parameter is formatted "address, number, rooms, rent".
  try {
     apartments[0] = new Apartment("123 Fake Street, 456, 3, 1500"); // valid.
     apartments[1] = new Apartment("21 Blizzard Avenue, 333, 2, 2600"); // invalid rent.
     apartments[2] = new Apartment("6 Brr Street, 23, 1, 1000"); // invalid number.
     apartments[3] = new Apartment("25 Boat Lane, 324, 5, 1200"); // invalid rooms.
     apartments[4] = new Apartment("47 Kenneth Street, 550, 1, 1000"); // valid.
     apartments[5] = new Apartment("36 Sanders Drive, 230, 1, 1300"); // valid.
  }
  catch(ApartmentException mistake) {

  }
}
}

-----------------------------------------
Output:
Apartment 123 Fake Street, 456, 3, 1500 was successfully initialised.
Apartment 21 Blizzard Avenue, 333, 2, 2600 failed to be instantiated, one or more of the values was outside of valid range.
```

The current options I have open that I think may fix the problem are:

1: Place each object instantiation in it's own try/catch block.

2: Restructure the program so that the try/catch block is performed inside the Apartment constructor.

3: Be informed of some way of formatting a loop that allows for unique object instantiation like this, I could probably use an array of Strings but that seems like an incredibly awkward duct tape solution, not an actual solution.

Comment: Both 1 and 2 should work. I think 2 is better as it's more robust and you [Don't Repeat Yourself](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself). However this isn't actually posed as a question so I'm going to vote to close (which will give you a chance to edit it into a proper question)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I would do:

1- Let the `Apartment Class` throws the exception if an invalid input is passed to it (`ApartmentException` in your case)

2- Use List instead of arrays like the following:

```
List<Apartment> myList = new ArrayList<Apartment>();

String[] desc = new String {"123 Fake Street, 456, 3, 1500", ... }

for(int i=0; i<desc.length; i++)
{
   try
   {
      myList.add(new Apartment(desc[i]));
   }
   catch(ApartmentException mistake)
   {
      //do something
   }
}

//at this point myList contains only valid listings
```

Comment: So you'd have an array of Apartment information strings? I suppose if this was going to be an actual program instead of just an exercise, user input, if it were to be in such a "fragile" format, would be stored as an array. I'll give that a shot. I'm still not quite certain what the best practices for custom Exceptions is.

EDIT: Well, array or list.

Comment: @SpaceOstrich since your Apartment constructor gets String as input you eventually have to convert the user input into a String

Comment: Funnily enough there is no user input for this program. A hypothetical practical example would probably be as part of some automated apartment registry, checking them for validity or price/bedroom range. All input is made via instantiated object strings before runtime.

I'll probably reformat this question to be more specific.

Comment: @SpaceOstrich what ever mechanism you use, (reading data from user, crawling other sites,...) at some point you need to convert your data to suit the constructor of your Apartment class (either String, or some other data types)

Comment: Marking this as answered, as I did solve the problem and I did get some useful information out of the question. However, it is pretty useless for anybody other than me to look at, so I'm in favour of it being closed.